# Where is a photo saved to when using Camera intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, photos

On the common intents documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

It says you can capture a picture or video and return it.

My question is, where should the photo be saved ?:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final Uri mLocationForPhotos;

public void capturePhoto(String targetFilename) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.withAppendedPath(mLocationForPhotos, targetFilename));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

What should mLocationForPhotos be ? I want to support Android versions from 4.4 to 7.0, and since there are changes in the way the file system is handled in different versions, which is a safe place to save photos ?

Comment: in target file path u gave ..

Comment: @jagapathi where should I save it ?

Comment: that depends on your requirement I save it in my app folder

Comment: @jagapathi But if you save it in your app folder using getExternalFilesDir(), then the files are private to your app. I want the files to be visible in the gallery etc...

Comment: Then you have to do nothing. The camera app will save the file in probably the DCIM folder. Do not use putExtra().